# Strategy for using emacs now that Apple removed the escape key?

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Apple removed the escape key and replaced it with the OLED touch bar. This has implications for emacs users, particularly for UNIX/emacs users who have decades of muscle memory to overcome with this change. Fortunately the touch bar escape key appears to always be there when you need it, but is more difficult to feel and is offset from the tilde key making it even more difficult.

Time will tell if it is possible to retrain muscle memory to reliably hit this new escape key, but in the meantime I am looking for another strategy to replace the escape key when using emacs.

Any help?

Comment: I'm curious, when are you hitting `Esc`?  I'm guessing you're using it instead of using `Meta/Alt`?

Comment: That's correct. I'm not in front of my computer right now, but does the option/alt key work on a Mac keyboard? I think there was something early on in my Emacs use back in the 90s where escape was the only key I could get to work for Meta/alt and I started using escape. AFAIK it's the only option on a Mac keyboard. I could be wrong.

Comment: So I found an option in Terminal.app that lets you set Option as Meta key. However, the escape key can also exit typing a search or buffer command after a few taps while just the alt/meta key cannot. I wonder how to work around that...

Comment: I can only give advice based on my own experience, but I never use `keyboard-escape-quit` (bound to `M-Esc Esc`, or simply `Esc Esc Esc`), only `keyboard-quit` (bound to `C-g`).  These are clearly different but I'm unaware of the specific differences.  Maybe this would work for you too?  Another alternative would be to use `C-[` instead of `Esc`.  The keyboard I use has a very crappy `Esc` key so I've gotten used to using `C-[` whenever I'm using vim where `Esc` is pretty much a requirement.

Comment: Randy, that is actually very helpful. The rest of my response will be in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mapped key-board quit to C-g and that works well. Between setting the "Use Option as Meta Key" in Terminal.app's ***Edit*** Menu (which also adds a touch bar button to easily toggle this behavior) and mapping keyboard-quit I think I'm good to go.

Comment: Just a note, `C-g` should be bound to `keyboard-quit` by default.  You shouldn't have to add a mapping for it.

Comment: Wow, that's funny. It is also funny how I (others too?) can get stuck in patterns after 20 years of emacs use, and have no idea about really basic commands that I've never used.

Answer (score 0):

For Terminal.app provided by macOS, toggle "Use Option as Meta Key" in its ***Edit*** Menu.

For [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/), set Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Left Option Key to Esc+

[image]

Comment: Another answer found in [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems#toc15)